# Parsererror from web service RESTFul

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, jquery

I am trying to to use ajax and/or JSON for getting data from a Web service restful which I have build and deployed with the Labview software.

However I get errors (parsererror). For example. I have build a web service RESTFUL from a Labview vi

localhost:8080/math/divide/5/20 will give {"Z":4.000000} )

I get results when I run the web service with the browser (Chrome, Explorer,Safari or from Android application I have wrote) but I am getting errors for the below example.

When I use the source breakpoints the data read status is 4 and the data status is 200

I get in the console log the following massage:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :5&callback=jQuery15109152818964794278_1379778833104:1

does anyone know how should I call to a web service

```
url = "localhost:8080/math/divide/5/20&callback=?"

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

  }).done(function (data, status) {
    // doing something something

  }).fail(function (data,status) {
       alert(status);

  });
```

Comment: Have you tried setting url without a callback: url = "localhost:8080/math/divide/5/20"

Comment: Yes I have tried to do it

Comment: in your done callback can you read the data?

Comment: No, I can not read the data since I get parsereror